# realloc(): invalid next size when append item to array

Tags: c

realloc(): invalid next size occurs when i added 
`*(target_office->packages+(target_office->packages_count-1)) = *pkg;`.Error does not occurs without that line. I increeased the array size by one. But this doesn't work.

but `*(target_office->packages+(target_office->packages_count)) = *pkg;` this works. I can't understand why.

```
struct package
{
    char* id;
    int weight;
};

typedef struct package package;

struct post_office
{
    int min_weight;
    int max_weight;
    package* packages;
    int packages_count;
};

typedef struct post_office post_office;

struct town
{
    char* name;
    post_office* offices;
    int offices_count;
};

typedef struct town town;


void send_all_acceptable_packages(town* source, int source_office_index, town* target, int target_office_index) {   
    post_office* source_office = (source->offices+source_office_index);
    post_office* target_office = (target->offices+target_office_index);

    for(int package_i=0; package_i<source_office->packages_count; package_i++){
        package* pkg = source_office->packages+package_i;
        if(pkg->weight>=target_office->min_weight && pkg->weight<=target_office->max_weight){
            target_office->packages_count++;
            target_office->packages = (package *) realloc(target_office->packages,target_office->packages_count);
            *(target_office->packages+(target_office->packages_count-1)) = *pkg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The second parameter of `realloc` needs to be a size in bytes not an element count. Looks like it should be `target_office->packages_count * sizeof(target_office->offices)`. If that isn't the problem then please post a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @kaylum Thank you very much. All this time i misunderstand about the realloc. It was very helpful ♥♥♥